# What's the differnce between "Connection timed out" v/s "No route to host" for ncat command?

Tags: linux, networking, tcp, arp, icmp

I tried to use ncat command to 2 diff unknown IPs from a CENTOS 7 (linux) terminal.

```
[abc@localhost ~]$ ncat -zv 10.11.78.5 22
Ncat: Version 7.50 ( https://nmap.org/ncat )
Ncat: No route to host.
[abc@localhost ~]$ ncat -zv 10.11.215.243 22
Ncat: Version 7.50 ( https://nmap.org/ncat )
Ncat: Connection timed out.
```

In case case 1 , we I use tcpdump to see

```
10.11.77.147.22 > 10.11.236.41.55722: Flags [P.], cksum 0x4ef1 (incorrect -> 0xcc2c), seq 2565:2601, ack 1124, win 318, options [nop,nop,TS val 523166642 ecr 4195774342], length 36
13:57:39.271990 [SOURCE_MAC] > ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff, ethertype ARP (0x0806), length 42: Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Request who-has 10.11.78.5 tell 10.11.77.147, length 28
13:57:39.272428 [SOURCE_MAC] > [DEST_MAC], ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 150: (tos 0x12,ECT(0), ttl 64, id 2262, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 136)
    10.11.77.147.22 > 10.11.236.41.55722: Flags [P.], cksum 0x4f21 (incorrect -> 0x12b6), seq 2601:2685, ack 1124, win 318, options [nop,nop,TS val 523166656 ecr 4195774342], length 84
13:57:39.641351 [SRC_MAC] > [DEST_MAC], ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 66: (tos 0x48, ttl 58, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    10.11.236.41.55722 > 10.11.77.147.22: Flags [.], cksum 0x580f (correct), ack 2601, win 2047, options [nop,nop,TS val 4195774724 ecr 523166642], length 0
13:57:39.641351 [SRC_MAC] > [DEST_MAC], ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 66: (tos 0x48, ttl 58, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    10.11.236.41.55722 > 10.11.77.147.22: Flags [.], cksum 0x57ae (correct), ack 2685, win 2046, options [nop,nop,TS val 4195774724 ecr 523166656], length 0
13:57:40.272221 [SOURCE_MAC] > ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff, ethertype ARP (0x0806), length 42: Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Request who-has 10.11.78.5 tell 10.11.77.147, length 28
```

In case case 2 , we I use tcpdump then I see:

```
15:27:20.847566 SRC_MAC > DEST_MAC, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 102: (tos 0x4a,ECT(0), ttl 58, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 88)
    10.11.236.41.56347 > 10.11.77.147.22: Flags [P.], cksum 0x3679 (correct), seq 3046:3082, ack 2950, win 2048, options [nop,nop,TS val 3721004625 ecr 528532842], length 36
15:27:20.860097 DEST_MAC > SRC_MAC, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 102: (tos 0x12,ECT(0), ttl 64, id 35536, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 88)
    10.11.77.147.22 > 10.11.236.41.56347: Flags [P.], cksum 0x0cb5 (correct), seq 2950:2986, ack 3082, win 318, options [nop,nop,TS val 528548224 ecr 3721004625], length 36
15:27:20.860124 DEST_MAC > SRC_MAC, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 150: (tos 0x12,ECT(0), ttl 64, id 35537, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 136)
    10.11.77.147.22 > 10.11.236.41.56347: Flags [P.], cksum 0xfd88 (correct), seq 2986:3070, ack 3082, win 318, options [nop,nop,TS val 528548231 ecr 3721004625], length 84
15:27:20.865395 DEST_MAC > SRC_MAC, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 74: (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 15451, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 60)
    10.11.77.147.58106 > 10.11.215.243.22: Flags [S], cksum 0xcab1 (correct), seq 2395880917, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 528548238 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
15:27:21.178240 SRC_MAC > DEST_MAC, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 66: (tos 0x48, ttl 58, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    10.11.236.41.56347 > 10.11.77.147.22: Flags [.], cksum 0x990d (correct), ack 2986, win 2047, options [nop,nop,TS val 3721004956 ecr 528548224], length 0
15:27:21.178240 SRC_MAC > DEST_MAC, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 66: (tos 0x48, ttl 58, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    10.11.236.41.56347 > 10.11.77.147.22: Flags [.], cksum 0x98b3 (correct), ack 3070, win 2046, options [nop,nop,TS val 3721004956 ecr 528548231], length 0
15:27:21.867037 DEST_MAC > SRC_MAC, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 74: (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 15452, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 60)
    10.11.77.147.58106 > 10.11.215.243.22: Flags [S], cksum 0xc6c7 (correct), seq 2395880917, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 528549240 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
15:27:23.870566 DEST_MAC > SRC_MAC, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 74: (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 15453, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 60)
    10.11.77.147.58106 > 10.11.215.243.22: Flags [S], cksum 0x3aa9 (incorrect -> 0xbef3), seq 2395880917, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 528551244 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
15:27:23.996114 SRC_MAC > DEST_MAC, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 102: (tos 0xc0, ttl 58, id 50466, offset 0, flags [none], proto ICMP (1), length 88)
    10.11.26.4 > 10.11.77.147: ICMP host 10.11.215.243 unreachable, length 68
    (tos 0x0, ttl 57, id 15451, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 60)
    10.11.77.147.58106 > 10.11.215.243.22: Flags [S], cksum 0xcaf6 (correct), seq 2395880917, win 29200, options [mss 1391,sackOK,TS val 528548238 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
15:27:23.996114 SRC_MAC > DEST_MAC, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 102: (tos 0xc0, ttl 58, id 50467, offset 0, flags [none], proto ICMP (1), length 88)
    10.11.26.4 > 10.11.77.147: ICMP host 10.11.215.243 unreachable, length 68
    (tos 0x0, ttl 57, id 15452, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 60)
    10.11.77.147.58106 > 10.11.215.243.22: Flags [S], cksum 0xc70c (correct), seq 2395880917, win 29200, options [mss 1391,sackOK,TS val 528549240 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
15:27:26.999948 SRC_MAC > DEST_MAC, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 102: (tos 0xc0, ttl 58, id 50468, offset 0, flags [none], proto ICMP (1), length 88)
    10.11.26.4 > 10.11.77.147: ICMP host 10.11.215.243 unreachable, length 68
```

It starts from 10.xx so Private IPs. Also I've santised mac addresses for obv reasons.

1. Both IPs seem unreachable, but we have diff in output?
2. In one case we get ICMP packet while that is absent in other?
3. "Connection timed out" v/s "No route to host"
4. What more to search for the real cause?

local host : 10.11.77.147

Comment: Please restrict your tcpdump to the actual IP addresses you are interested in. There is too much noise in your output from unrelated traffic.

Comment: Your local host is 10.11.77.147 and a connection to 10.12.78.5 produces an ARP query? You're not running the whole of 10/8 as a single LAN, are you..? Even 10.10/14 would be rather on the largish side, to say the least.

Comment: sorry for confusion it's 10.11.x.y.z is actually 10.aa.x.y.z ,10.bb.x.y.z,10.cc.x.y.z, wanted to hide actual ips

Comment: @ilkkachu what should i search more ?

Answer (score 2):

In the first one, there are ARP requests for 10.11.78.5, but no corresponding replies. The system can't send packets to that destination if it doesn't know the layer 2 address. Note that are no TCP SYN packets destined to 10.11.78.5, it just doesn't get that far. An ARP entry is a sort of a host route, so it's at least plausible the situation gives the "no route to host" error. (I didn't check any official source, but it does seem to match the behaviour I get on Linux.)

```
13:57:39.271990 ... ARP (0x0806), ... Request who-has 10.11.78.5 tell 10.11.77.147, length 28
```

---

In the second one, there are no ARP requests, but a TCP SYN is sent. So it's likely that 10.11.215.243 is already in the system's ARP cache.

Here, you are getting ICMP errors back (at least as far as tcpdump sees them) and I would *expect* that to lead to some other error rather than just a timeout. Then again, it's probably worth checking you're not actively dropping incoming ICMP packets with e.g. iptables?

```
15:27:23.996114 ... IPv4 (0x0800), ... proto ICMP (1), length 88)
    10.11.26.4 > 10.11.77.147: ICMP host 10.11.215.243 unreachable, length 68
```

---

Anyway, the TCP packets to/from 10.11.236.41 seem unrelated to the connections you're testing with. They seem be connected to 10.11.77.147/tcp22 on the other end, is that perhaps the SSH connection your shell session is running over? You might want to filter out packets like that to make the dump easier to read.